# Strange Sage behavior grobner bases

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sagemath, groebner-basis

I have the following code in Sage

```
R.<a, b, c, d, e> = PolynomialRing(CC, 5, order='negdeglex')
I = ideal(a^3 - 1, b^3 - 1, c^3 - 1, d^3 - 1, e^3 - 1,
          a^2 + a*b + b^2, b^2 + b*d + d^2,
          c^2 + c*d + d^2, c^2 + c*e + e^2)

I.groebner_basis()
```

If I execute this Sage code I get a reduced Grobner base that is not $\{1\}$. If I use `order='negdegrevlex'` instead of lex, the reduced Grobner base is $\{1\}$.

How is that possible? The reduced Grobner base is $1$ if and only if the system formed by those polynomials $=0$ does not have solutions, no matter what monomial ordering I use.

Comment: I get output `[1.00000000000000]` for both `negdeglex` and `negdegrevlex`. [Here is a SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzNT8sKwjAQvBf6D3trWmPBijfrpafepB8QyWMJgZhIKqJ_71ZsEbx5cheGYWZ32RnqveSgOGgOhgMeoIVj9I8Qz076wQXLuo7DjkNMBlNbBLQGrcd7UeZZT9POoPRMii2sYUOnZqJnYmaCb5JnsJQUDaxAVopQiWbanwRVGUJDwuewfnl68RYBCVE09NEluXBlfW1TRBUwnZQc3chKsqYefoub8Pa3ib-zPgG6T3Lz&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) with the computation. Why are you working over $\mathbb{C}$? If you're getting something else, it could very well be due to rounding.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn I found the problem. Actually ```negdeglex``` is not a monomial ordering. I think it's not a well ordering actually, and the proposition "The reduced Grobner base is 1
 if and only if..." is true only for monomial orderings. See Cox Little O'Shea Ideals Varieties and Algorithms. Thanks a lot tho